# 3 monitor support for 6950, 5830, or 5850?

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I have 3 graphics cards and three monitors: one Acer X233H two Acer X203H's. The X233H has an HDMI cable I want to use, and the other will use either VGA or DVI, it doesn't matter.

Is it possible to get a 3 monitor setup with these three monitors, one of these graphics cards, and the cables mentioned? I'm running Ubuntu 12.04, best regards!

Comment: -1 for research effort. what graphics card are you going to use? it doesn't necessarily matter what the interface is as long as there's 1) physically enough connectors and 2) driver support.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "6950", "5830" and "5850" refer to models of the **AMD Radeon HD** series of graphics cards...

Question 1: Are you using `fglrx` or are you using `radeon`? `fglrx` is the proprietary (closed-source) driver and `radeon` is the open source graphics driver. In theory both sholuld be able to support the same number of monitors, but in practice `fglrx` is more likely to result in success -- especially for the HD6950, which is a generation newer than the more-tested HD5000 series which works well on the `radeon` driver.

Question 2: You aren't trying to put these cards in any kind of crossfire mode, right? You do realize that on Linux there is **absolutely no** support for multiple graphics cards operating at the same time on the same display server, so any effort to use all 3 cards would require using three separate X servers...

Anyway, regardless of your monitors, you can buy connectors/converters/cables until you're blue in the face and eventually get all of them running. The simplest (but not the least expensive) way would be to plug them all into a MSP DisplayPort 1.2 hub and connect each monitor to the hub via a converter cable from the native input format to DP. But for the one with native HDMI you can just plug it straight into the card. HD6950 will support MSP.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, this is certainly possible. In practice, you may find a couple of potential issues:

- Are you sure you have sufficient power from your power supply to reliably run 3 cards?
- Complex X configurations are notoriously difficult to get working

Having said that, here are a couple of related questions that contain some answers:

- [How can I get multiple video cards to work on linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/117239/how-can-i-get-multiple-video-cards-to-work-on-linux)
- [How to configure multiple video cards in linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/135014/how-to-configure-multiple-video-cards-in-linux)

The second relates to NVidia cards but may still be of some use.

UPDATE: The last part of your question relates to using ONE card with 3 monitors - this won't be possible of course. Though, depending on the graphics card, you might be able to run three monitors from two cards if one of the cards is supported in Linux for dual monitor output.